# Scala, check for overflow of Double

Tags: scala, exception, overflow

Scala noobie here, professionally programmed in C#, R, and Perl. How do you check for a Double overflow? Do you have to roll your own? See code below and output. As far as I can tell, a radius of 999 overflows. I would like to throw an error for the overflow. Thanks

```
case class LessThanZeroEx(private val message:String = "Less than zero") extends Exception(message){}  
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine

println("Scala exception test")
println("Get area and circumference of a circle.")
val radius:Integer = getNumFromCon("Please enter a radius: ")
val circum = getCircum(radius)
val area = getArea(radius)
println("The circumference is " + circum + " and the area is " + area)

def getNumFromCon(prompt:String):Int = 
{
  val input:String = readLine(prompt)
  var rv:Integer = 0
  try
  {
    rv = input.toInt
    if(rv < 0) throw LessThanZeroEx("message")
  } catch
  {
    case fe : NumberFormatException => {
      println("Your input was not in the correct format")
      rv = getNumFromCon(prompt)}
    case ltz : LessThanZeroEx => {
      println("Your input was less than zero")
      rv = getNumFromCon(prompt)}
  }
  return rv
}

def getCircum(radius:Integer):Double = 
{
  return 2.0 * math.Pi * radius
}

def getArea(radius:Integer):Double = 
{
  return math.Pi * radius * radius
}
```

output---

```
>scala exception-test.scala
Scala exception test
Get area and circumference of a circle.
Please enter a radius: 99
The circumference is 622.0353454107791 and the area is 30790.749597833565

>scala exception-test.scala
Scala exception test
Get area and circumference of a circle.
Please enter a radius: 999
The circumference is 6276.9021218724065 and the area is 3135312.609875267

>scala exception-test.scala
Scala exception test
Get area and circumference of a circle.
Please enter a radius: 9999
The circumference is 62825.56988648868 and the area is 3.1409643664750016E8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't overflow. The last result is printed in scientific notation: it is not `~3.14` but rather `~3.14 * 10^8` (which is correct).

Technicaly `Double` operations could overflow but you need to try really hard for it: `Double.MAX_VALUE` is approximately `10^308`.

Comment: Good, thank you. As I said, new to Scala, and didn't expect this notation. Thank you.